# Odd and even function properties...

Tags: functions

Does it mean when the function is even it's in 100% cases y-axis symmetric, and when it's odd it's in 100% cases origin symmetric?

Comment: Yes that is the geometric interpretation of even or oddness.

Comment: Thanks, and if it's not symmetric, then it's not even nor odd i guess.

Comment: That is true.  If a function has no lines of symmetry in the plane, then it cannot be even or odd.

Comment: @Riemann1337 Thanks. You can, if you want, post an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the geometric interpretation of even or oddness.  Also, if a function has no lines of symmetry in the plane, then it cannot be even or odd.